# Does Laravel or PHP a max file size in storage folder?

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel-Backup from Spatie.

Till last Friday, everything worked well. Then I did an update. Now, `php artisan backup:run` occurs the following error:

Backup failed because: ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied.

When I run `php artisan backup:run --only-db` everything works well.

When I exclude the storage folder (size around 200MB) everything works well.

I searched for a solution. But the only thing I found was to set the folder on 777. But this is not the problem.

Does I increase some file limit on Laravel or PHP?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/app/backup-temp`

Comment: Thanks. But the permission is still on 777

Comment: then check `backup.php` there one key is `exclude` exclude all the folder wich has wrong permission like if php not able to copy those thing then it throw this error

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh, that was the problem